# Would it be grammatically correct to use the phrase "right up your strasse"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I heard the phrase "right up your strasse" used in the BBC TV mini-series Sherlock. When I didn't find the phrase in the dictionary, I searched online and found the link given below. Now I was wondering that would the phase the eligible for usage in my school essays. Would the teachers strike it off if I were to use the phase? Would it be grammatically wrong to use the phase in essays and stuff?

[Urban dictionary's saying on the phrase](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term%3Dstrasse&hl=en-IN)

Comment: It's not really any more "idiomatic" than [*right up your **rue***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=GPb2Wt3ICKW96ATS2aKoCg&q=%22right+up+your+rue%22&oq=%22right+up+your+rue%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.74695.77015.0.77425.10.10.0.0.0.0.247.1285.0j8j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.393...0i13i30k1.0.uCW7XAwIReg) (replacing ***street*** with French ***rue*** rather than German ***strasse***). They're both (somewhat affected) "nonce usages" that you should *definitely* avoid in relatively formal contexts such as essays.

Comment: Also, the idiomatic (American) English phrase is *right up your **alley***.

Comment: Grammar has nothing to do with this one. It's that "Straße" is a German word not at all in general use in English. It seems likely that the show had set up a context in which the wry or witty use of the word would have made sense *in that particular circumstance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Right up your strasse* is a British slang variation of “right up your street,” substituting the German word *Straße* ‘street’, but usually following English spelling conventions. While the original context may have had something to do with a German-speaking country:

> **Done Berlin? Try Frankfurt**
> If you're drawn to Berlin's clubbing, culture and history, Frankfurt will be [right up your strasse](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/from-lisbon-to-lyon-five-city-break-destinations-you-should-try-10071893.html). — *Independent*, 26.02.15.

that has long since disappeared.

> 21.08.2005 · MartinC wrote: Quote. Can someone please buy these as my bank account is getting worried! Go on Martin, buy em. You'll love what they do to the Audiolab Dac, [right up your strasse](https://hifiwigwam.com/forum/topic/236-belcanto-evo-2002s-pair/) mate.
>
> 13.09.2006 The Jack Starr is just classic Norton. Really primitive mental rockabilly trash. Certainly not novelty and if you dig The Haze or Stud Cole, it'd be [right up your strasse](https://www.verygoodplus.co.uk/forum/let-s-talk/let-s-get-stuck-into-the-music/10835-back-from-the-us-of-a).
>
> 25.07.2008 · BUT Mamma Mia rocks, my friend nearly fainted she enjoyed it so much. Its utterly loveable cheeseball with kareoke. Great Swedish art direction as well. Sounds [right up your strasse](https://thisrecording.wordpress.com/2008/07/25/in-which-all-of-our-opinions-are-right/).
>
> 08.05.2018· If you're a big Robot Wars fan then this is [right up your straße](https://www.facebook.com/ChallengeTV/)!

I would suggest that besides its novelty the reason Britons are attracted to this version is not some sudden fondness for the German language or where it’s spoken, but that the addition of an extra syllable makes the expression scan much better, like the American “right up your alley.”

As a slang expression, it would be inappropriate in an academic essay unless your topic deals with the use of slang.The same would go for the original “right up your street.”

Comment: If you really want to confuse 'em, say "It's right up your ulitsa."  (That's Russian and Bulgarian for street.)

Comment: For the rhythm, it would have to be the Hungarian loanword _utca_.